# Android Unit Test Issue

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

```
package com.rajitha.medi.activities;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.view.View;
import com.allion.medimap.R;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull;

/**
 * Created by rajitha on 8/10/17.
 */

public class ActivationActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<ActivationActivity> activityActivityTestRule= new ActivityTestRule<ActivationActivity>(ActivationActivity.class);
    public ActivationActivity activationActivity;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        activationActivity=activityActivityTestRule.getActivity();
    }

    @Test
    public void testrun()
    {
        View view=activationActivity.findViewById(R.id.activationCode);
        assertNotNull(view);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        activationActivity = null;
    }

}
            View view=activationActivity.findViewById(R.id.activationCode);
            assertNotNull(view);
        }

        @After
        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            activationActivity = null;
        }

    }
```

> Here I added Unit test class for my ActivationActivity class.but I got one issue called **error: cannot find symbol import com.rajitha.medi.R;**
>    my project package name is
>   **com.rajitha.medi** How can I fix that?
>
> Logcat-Here I attached the logcat part which shows the another error.Hope one reason for both issues.

```
error: cannot find symbol
    public ActivationActivity activationActivity;
           ^
  symbol:   class ActivationActivity
  location: class ActivationActivityTest
```

Comment: What is your application package?

Comment: Hi, I changed it.Now you can see it clearly.

Comment: Don't you use AS for writing code? It should autoimport Activity class